# Remove set of elements from list A and add into list B using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I am attempting to lean linq by replacing existing code in a project with linq calls. In this method I check for a condition in my list of lines and if the condition is true, move that element from lines to processedLines.

The data structures are just lists:

```
List<LineSegment2> lines;
List<LineSegment2> processedLines;
```

The original code was:

```
for (int i = lines.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{           
   if (lines[i].P2.x < sweepPosition)
   {
      processedLines.Add(lines[i]);
      lines.RemoveAt(i);
   }
}
```

and my linq code is:

```
var toMove = lines.FindAll(x => x.P2.x < sweepPosition);
toMove.ForEach(x =>
{
   processedLines.Add(x);
   lines.Remove(x);
});
```

My question is: Is this linq code less efficient because it is using more memory creating the temporary list 'toMove'. Is there a way to create the linq query without requiring the temporary list or is the original code always more efficient?

Comment: Your "LINQ" code doesn't use LINQ at all. Both FindAll and ForEach were present in .NET 2, and aren't part of LINQ.

Comment: you dont need to add all elements of `toMove` to `processedLines`, you can just let `processedLines` be the result of calling `FindAll`

Comment: @weidi: That's assuming that `processedLines` is empty.

Comment: @Skeet It definitely looks like I've confused delegates + foreach/findall and the various LINQ extensions. Thanks for clearing things up.

Comment: @weidi When you combine the foreach on the end rather than put it in a temporary variable does that cause the enumerator to pass each value one by one from the FindAll to the ForEach or does it complete the entire FindAll and then being the ForEach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more LINQy solution would be to add all the processed lines at once, then get the remaining lines:

```
processedLines.AddRange(lines.Where(x => x.P2.x < sweepPosition));
lines = lines.Where(x => x.P2.x >= sweepPosition).ToList();
```

As for efficiency, it won't be quite as fast as your original code. That's not why you use LINQ.

There is one potential advantage, though. It will make a new list of lines, so if you move a lot of lines to the processed list it will get rid of the unused items in the list.

Answer (score 1):

The "linq" code is less efficient and (more importantly) not necessarily much easier to maintain. Stick with your original code if you must choose between these two alternatives.  I'd just recommend you run the `for` loop forward -- no reason you should run it backwards like you're doing.

As a side note, I wonder if it would be appropriate for your use case to just maintain a single list and add an `IsProcessed` property to the `LineSegment2` class. You might consider that.

Comment: Thanks. I definitely prefer the old code as it's what I'm used to, but I'm just using this project as an excuse to practice using LINQ / delegates / lambdas. Good to know that it is less efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure about the efficiency...but in Linq I'll do it like this

```
processedLines = processedLines.Concat(lines.Where(x => x < sweepPosition)).ToList();
lines.RemoveAll(x => x < sweepPosition);
```

Comment: It looks like processedLines.AddRange(lines.Where(x => x.P2.x < sweepPosition)); works and you don't need the extra .toList and assignment. Still doesn't really use linq except for the single where clause.